# R lattice barchart control range

Tags: r, rstudio, lattice

In R lattice, how do I get a bar chart where the bars are emanating from the middle y=0 axis instead of the bottom so right now if the values are from -20 to 20, every bar extend from y=-20 so they are flush on the bottom.  Right now just using something very basic like
barchart(V3~V1,  data = differences,col=c("forestgreen") )

I want it to look like this.

```
  o
 oo
ooo  
   ooo
    oo
     o

isntead of
  o
 oo
ooo  
oooo
ooooo
oooooo
```

I hope that makes sense.  Also how do you control the individual bars in the bar chart so it doesn't have border or fading properties if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191750/barchart-in-r-using-lattice

Answer (score 2):

Add `origin=0` as argument:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(-2:2),y=letters[1:5])
barchart(x~y, data=dat, origin=0)
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Or `barchart(y~x, data=dat, origin=0, horizontal=TRUE)`, to get the horizontal bars described by the OP.

Comment: when I did that it rotated the bars by 90 degrees so they are horizontal now.  I had problems with this earlier as well it seems sometimes changing x~y to y~x changes the orientation of the bars from vertical to horizontal but sometimes it doesn't.  Is there an option to specify?